# vue is not displaying the correct information

Tags: vue.js

So I am working at a hud for my gta v server and I use vue for it. Everything works perfect except one thing which doesn't get the right value. It would show Helper undefined when I open the hud and I can't figure out why because using the same code I use for helpers I get the correct information for admins.

This is the code I use to display the value:

```
<div class="mb-4" v-if="getClass('helpers').length > 0">
          <div class="page-subtitle">
            <div class="value">{{getClass('helpers').length}}</div>
            <div class="text">Helpers</div>
          </div>
          <div v-for="(x, index) in getClass('helpers')" v-bind:key="index" class="online-entry">
            <div class="text">
              {{x.name}} ({{x.id}}) 
              <span v-if="x.helper != 0" class="badge bg-warning text-dark small rounded p-2 ml-2">{{x.helper == 1337 ? 'Helpers Leader' : 'Helper ' + x.helper}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="value">
              {{x.ping}}
              <i class="fas fa-signal ml-1" :style="x.ping > 50 ? 'color: red' : 'color: green'"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And this is the getClass function:

```
getClass: function(clasa) {
    if(clasa == 'civillians') {
      let arrayPlayers = [];
      this.modalData.players.forEach((player, index) => {
        if(player.admin != 0) return;
        if(player.helper != 0) return;
        if(player.leader != 0) return;
        if(player.member != 0) return;
        if(player.premium != 0) return;
        arrayPlayers.push(player);
      });
      return arrayPlayers;
    }
    if(clasa == 'admins') {
      let arrayPlayers = [];
      this.modalData.players.forEach((player, index) => {
        if(player.admin == 0) return;
        arrayPlayers.push(player);
      });
      return arrayPlayers;
    }
    if(clasa == 'helpers') {
      let arrayPlayers = [];
      this.modalData.players.forEach((player, index) => {
        if(player.helper == 0) return;
        arrayPlayers.push(player);
      });
      return arrayPlayers;
    }
    if(clasa == 'premium') {
      let arrayPlayers = [];
      this.modalData.players.forEach((player, index) => {
        if(player.premium == 0) return;
        if(player.admin != 0) return;
        if(player.helper != 0) return;
        arrayPlayers.push(player);
      });
      return arrayPlayers;
    }
  },
```

Comment: In which line does it show Helper undefined?

Comment: This is the line `<span v-if="x.helper != 0" class="badge bg-warning text-dark small rounded p-2 ml-2">{{x.helper == 1337 ? 'Helpers Leader' : 'Helper ' + x.helper}}</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to send the helper value from database when I wrote that.